# How to adjust Gameplay at a PokerLeague?

Tags: nlhe, online, strategy, mtt

Every Weekend I take part at a little Poker league , that has 15MTTs and the result of the best 10 count towards the leaderboard , 
There is no prize for a single MTT so you only play fore Points ... all prizes go to the leaderboard . 
There are around 100players and best 7 from the Leaderboard are paid . 
At every MTT you get 3points for every player that busts before you bust . 
My question is , How do I adjust my Game in EarlyStage , Midstage and Latestage , compared to a normal MTT ... 
Do I have to play tight at the Early Stage to make sure I gain some points ? 
Or can I play loose because it doesn t matter if I bust early because the 5 worst results don t count ? 
Thank you for your help .

Comment: I am not following the format.   How can you have 15 MTTs 100 players?   Do you have 100 in each of the 15 for 1500 players?

Comment: there are 100 players at the leaderboard , on average there are 70 each MTT ... so not everyone is playing every MTT .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an interesting structure.  I would play pretty tight at all stages with the mindset of surviving as long as possible.  Once you have 10 outcomes that you're satisfied with, and maybe a couple MTT's left, that's when I would more aggressively go for higher spots to try and improve your overall standing.

In a normal MTT that pays cash, you generally see 10-20% of the field getting paid and the actual payouts increase almost exponentially so that 1st place is worth a lot more than 15th place or even 3rd place.  With that structure, there is plenty of incentive to aggressively go after chips and take some chances since there's such a dramatic benefit to placing high.

In the structure that you describe, everybody gets a payout and they only increase linearly so there shouldn't be such a strong incentive to aggressively accumulate chips.  For instance, say you've made it to be in the last 7 people of one of these MTTs.  By getting first place, you'll earn 6*3 = 18 additional points.  On the other hand, say you're part of the pack with 100 left--by making it to the final 94, you'll also earn 18 additional points.  In other words, it doesn't matter what stage of the tournament you're at, it's always similarly profitable to outlast as many people as possible.

Of course, you'll want to go as long as possible and that will entail getting enough chips to survive.  But I wouldn't take a lot of risks and don't worry about trying to get a big stack--it's just not worth as much as it would be in an MTT with regular payouts.